# How to dynamically generate tasks via an XCOM dictionary for a a non TaskInstance operator?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I have a dag that outputs a dictionary (map), passed through an XCom.

I want to generate a number of tasks according to the keys of said XCom dictionary.

This is how the dictionary looks in the xcom :

```
{
    "F1": {
        "source": {
            "project": "legacy_project",
            "bucket": "legacy_bucket",
            "prefix": "prefix/{{ds_nodash}}/F1",
            "files": [
                "file_1.csv"
            ]
        },
        "destination": {
            "project_id": "new_project_1",
            "bucket": "new_bucket_1",
            "prefix": "DTM/F1/{{ds_nodash}}"
        }
    },
    "F2": {
        "source": {
            "project": "legacy_project",
            "bucket": "legacy_bucket",
            "prefix": "prefix/{{ds_nodash}}/F2",
            "files": [
                "file_1.csv"
            ]
        },
        "destination": {
            "project_id": "new_project_2",
            "bucket": "new_bucket_2",
            "prefix": "DTM/F2/{{ds_nodash}}"
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Notice that I used `{{ds_nodash}}` in the generated xcom in order for it to be replaced by the date of execution of the dag.

What I want, is to create a task for each of `F1,F2,...,Fn` and input the  `F1["source"]["bucket"]`, `F1["source"]["prefix"]` into a `GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor`, with a custom `task_id` for each task..

Something like this :

```py
for f_key in <xcom_output_dict>:
    GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor(
       task_id = f"{f_key}_sensor",
       bucket = f_key["source"]["bucket"]
       prefix = f_key["source"]["prefix"]
    )
```

I tried [reading up](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) on `expand` and `partial`, but it's really unclear how one can pass the dictionary contents such as `bucket` and `prefix` to the task operator...

EDIT :

One of my trials :

```
    from airflow import DAG, XComArg
    from airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor import (
    GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor,
)
    ...
    
    generate_prefix_existance_sensor_kwargs = PythonOperator(
        task_id="generate_prefix_existance_sensor_kwargs",
        python_callable=gen_prefix_existance_sensor_kwargs,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={"effective_migration_map": "effective_migration_map"},
    )

    sensor_files = GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor.expand_kwargs(
        input=XComArg(generate_prefix_existance_sensor_kwargs),
    )

    (
        ... # Some other tasks
        >> generate_prefix_existance_sensor_kwargs
        >> sensor_files
    )
```

With the code to the kwargs generation function

```
def gen_prefix_existance_sensor_kwargs(ti, **kwargs) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    effective_migration_map = load_xcom_via_kwarg(
        ti=ti,
        key="effective_migration_map",
        default_value="effective_migration_map",
        kwargs=kwargs,
    )

    args_dicts = []
    for f_key in effective_migration_map:
        args_dicts.append(
            {
                "task_id": f_key,
                "bucket": effective_migration_map[f_key]["source"]["bucket"],
                "prefix": effective_migration_map[f_key]["source"]["prefix"],
            }
        )
    return args_dicts
```

But I get :

```
AttributeError: type object 'GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor' has no attribute 'expand_kwargs'
```

Which is weird because I saw an **Astronomer.io** video where it is used. I guess it isn't implemented yet in `Airflow 2.3.4`?

EDIT 1 :

I create the wrapper for the operator :

```py
class GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensorWrapper(
    GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor
):
    """This class is a temporary work around to using expand_kwargs(),
    as expand() can only take one argument,
    we must create a wrapper around every operator we use
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        src_or_dest: str,
        inp_parameters: Tuple[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]],
        **kwargs
    ):
        if src_or_dest not in ["source", "destination"]:
            raise TypeError(
                "Bad argument for src_or_dest, must be either 'source' or 'destination'"
            )

        else:
            bucket = inp_parameters[1][src_or_dest]["bucket"]
            prefix = inp_parameters[1][src_or_dest]["prefix"]
            super().__init__(
                bucket=bucket,
                prefix=prefix,
                **kwargs,
            )
```

I add it to my dag ..

```
updated_map_2 = match_data_with_migration_map(
    src_mig_map=updated_map_1,
    files_and_prefixes="{{ti.xcom_pull('list_files_and_prefixes')}}",
)

GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensorWrapper.partial(
    task_id="sensor_files",
    src_or_dest = "source",
    impersonation_chain=IMPERSONATED_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
).expand(inp_parameters=updated_map_2.output)
```

I get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'output'
```

EDIT 2 :

The previous task to this operator was not decorated correctly, so it created the "EDIT 1" problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to solve your issue with dynamic task mapping. However this solution has the down side that if you pass more parameters into the `expand()` it will make a [cross-product](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-over-multiple-parameters:%7E:text=names%20to%20tasks.-,Mapping%20over%20multiple%20parameters,cross%20product%22%2C%20calling%20the%20mapped%20task%20with%20each%20combination%20of%20parameters.,-%40task%0Adef%20add)

So my solution is to create a custom class that inherits from GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor and the init function assigns correct values:

```
class CustomExistenceSensor(GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor):
    def __init__(self, inp_params, **kwargs):
        bucket , prefix = inp_params
        super().__init__(bucket=bucket, prefix=prefix, **kwargs)
```

By using this class we can now expand the sensor and pass an iterable of parameters (bucket, prefix):

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.gcs import GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor

class CustomExistenceSensor(GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor):
    def __init__(self, inp_params, **kwargs):
        bucket , prefix = inp_params
        super().__init__(bucket=bucket, prefix=prefix, **kwargs)


@dag(
    schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 10, 21, hour=8),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['demo'],
)

def template_dag():
    """
    ### Template dag"""
    @task()
    def example_func():
        pass
    
    t1 = example_func()

#   Below just to test the sensor works
#   t3 = GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor(
#   task_id="test_check",
#   bucket="text_stack_bucket",
#   prefix="test_prefix"
#   prefix="prefix",
#   timeout=3)

#   t4 works but the issue here is that we can pass only array with one parameter if we pass more airflow will make a cross product 
#   t4 = GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor.partial(task_id="test_check_dynamic", bucket="text_stack_bucket", timeout=3).expand(prefix=["test_prefix", "prefix"])
 
    t5 = CustomExistenceSensor.partial(task_id="test_custom_class", timeout=2).expand(inp_params=[("text_stack_bucket", "test_prefix"), ("next_existing", "prefix")])
    t1 >> t2 >> t5

dag = template_dag()
```

So if you can amend a bit your code and make it return a list in xcom so that you can invoke it like so:

```
task = CustomExistenceSensor.partial(task_id='dynamic_tasks').expand(inp_params=previous_task.output)
```

Comment: the previous_task.output doesn't seem to work, it would probably only work with airflow>=2.4.. I am obliged to work with 2.3.4 here, otherwise I would have used expand_kwargs.. I edit my question to provide more details

Comment: Also, doing `updated_map_2 >> sensor_files` in my case returns the error `'dict' object has no attribute 'update_relative'`

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. My previous task was badly decorated by `@task` so that is what went wrong. Your answer is correct. Thank you !